# Upload eps or ai files into Drupal using scald

Tags: drupal, eps

**Goal**

When adding or editing a node in Drupal, I want to be able to upload an eps or ai file as an atom using Scald.

**Situation**

I created a content-type in Drupal and added an 'Atom reference' field. I set up the field so that it can accept Scald images. In the settings of the 'Scald Unified Atom Type image field' of the Scald structure admin page (under admin/structure/scald/image/fields) I added eps and ai to the available file extensions. I cleared all caches.

**Problem**

When I'm adding or editing a node and I want to use the Scald library to upload an eps file I immediately get a warning that an eps file can not be uploaded. The suggested file extensions do not include the eps extension that I've added before. What am I missing here?